# Should I pet my cat or just give him treats?

Tags: kleptocats

Petting my cat takes longer, and makes him less happy. Treats are faster and make him happy faster. I don't think it costs money to do either thing, so is there any detriment to just giving my cat treats all the time?

Comment: *points at title* I sense an out-of-context HNQ in the near future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although treats are quicker if you hold your finger on the cat, quickly tapping with petting raises the percentage more quickly.